# Passing Parameters in Ajax to JSON web service

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am using AJAX to request some information from a PHP built web service however the parameters I am passing doesn't seem to go to the web service my code is below:

```
$(document).on( "pageinit", "#player", function( e ) {
var passedId = (passDataObject.selectedHref != null ? passDataObject.selectedHref :    window.location.href).replace( /.*id=/, "" );
alert(passedId); // test passedId has the correct value within it 
var surl =  "a working url";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: surl,
    data: "&Track="+passedId,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache : false,
    jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
    jsonpCallback: "trackcallback",
    crossDomain: "true",
    success: function(response) {
       alert('tracks function');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {           
       alert('Unknown error ' + status);
    }       
 });        
});

//callback function for player page
function trackcallback(rtndata) 
{ 
alert(rtndata.track_name); // show up as undefined 
}
```

The passedId has the correct value within it and the URL is fine however the web service does not produce a result even though the SQL statement is fine. I am assuming the issue is within this line within my php web service `$id = $_REQUEST['Track'];` as this gets the value from the JavaScript to execute the SQL.
Can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Try appending the "&track=".passedId to the url like url:surl."&track...

Comment: `data: 'Track='+passedID` instead. `&` is only necessary if you're appending MULTIPLE query parameters - this will produce a query value of `&amp;Track=XXX`, and end up as `$_GET['&Track']`

Comment: Have you tried it with `data: {'Track':passedId},`

Comment: Also are you watching the request in firebug or developer tools?

Comment: @Shanimal I am using firebug

Comment: @MarcB I tried `data: 'Track='+passedID` and it is still undefined

Comment: how can I better monitor passedID as it doesn't seem to be going to the web service. Also am I alerting the value of the call back function correctly?

Comment: it seems my query is the issue in fact here is my query $query = "SELECT * FROM track WHERE track_id='$id'"; note that $id = $_REQUEST['Track']; seems to be working fine

Answer (score 0):

See this code below, there is no "&" before the parameter name:

> ```
>            $.ajax({
>                 url: homeUrl + "/Getsomething",
>                 data: "parameterhere=" +$(element).attr('attrHere'),
>                 type: 'GET',
>                 contentType: "application/json",
>                 dataType: "json",
>                 cache: false,
>                 success: function (result) {  
>                     //do stuff
>                 },
>                 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
>                     //error handling
>                 }
>             });
> ```

What happens if you do you ajax get like the code above?

Comment: @jjay25 none of these functions seem to put a value into the parameter I have used everything but nothing seems to work even my query was tested with actual data and it works therefore it is the variable being passed it doesn't seem to reach the php page

Comment: actually i printed the value gotten from the ajax request and the value is reaching the web service its just not getting the query results

Comment: in fact here is my query `$query = "SELECT * FROM track WHERE track_id='$id'";` note that `$id = $_REQUEST['Track'];` seems to be working fine

Comment: OK so to clarify the parameter value is getting through to the webservice and the parameter value goes through to your query?

Comment: yes actually i sloved the issue it was in the web service itself and not the actually ajax code seems my statements was correct all along.